# CCleaner for all user accounts

Tags: windows, maintenance, ccleaner

Is there an easy way to make CCleaner clear the browser caches, temp directories, recycle bins, etc., for all user accounts instead of just the one currently logged in? If not, is there a similar program that will help me clean up all the user accounts without having to log into each one?

Comment: One solution would be to use the PAID `Business Edition`.

Comment: @Ramhound thanks for the suggestion; I didn't even realize there was a business edition. I just looked though, and don't see anything that suggests there is an option to clean up all the user accounts at once. If you did find that feature, could you please post this solution as an answer and provide a link and a relevant excerpt from the web page?

Answer (score 0):

Would it be OK if it did it automatically when people log in? http://www.ghacks.net/2008/03/17/run-ccleaner-automatically-on-all-accounts/ contains a suggestion for that. I'm on a restricted computer so I didn't try it:

> Open the folder C:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Start Menu\Programs\Startup in Windows Explorer, right-click in that folder and select New > Shortcut from the menu. Now paste the command “C:\Program Files\CCleaner\ccleaner.exe” /AUTO into the first field.

Another suggestion is Temp File Cleaner (http://download.cnet.com/Temp-File-Cleaner/3000-2094_4-10628816.html); however, I have not used it.

Comment: Running CCleaner for everyone upon login won't quite cut it, because then I would have to make everyone log in whenever I'm trying to free up disk space.

Comment: I tried TFC, and unfortunately it also does not clean the other users' accounts.